# Difference between sizeof(*p) and sizeof(p)?

Tags: c, sizeof

I am using code below and getting different values.

```
int *p;

printf("Size of *p = %d", sizeof(*p));   // Here value is 4

printf("Size of p = %d", sizeof(p));    // Here value is 8
```

Can any one please explain, what exactly is the reason behind this?

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between `p` and `*p `?

Comment: The code, as show and even in a `main` function, should not build by the way. Remember your casing.

Comment: This is again a new question to me. Can you please explain the same.

Comment: And you should probably find a few text-books to read, or even some online tutorial about pointers.

Comment: I don't hink StackOverflow can be a replacement for the first few hundred hours of learning a new topic...

Comment: the operator: `sizeof` returns a `size_t` , not a `int`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any pointer variable `p`, the variable `p` itself is the pointer and the size of it is the size of the pointer. `*p` is what `p` is pointing to, and the size of `*p` is the size of what is being pointed to.

So when `sizeof(p)` reports `8` then you know that a pointer on your system is `8` bytes, and that you're probably on a 64-bit system.

If `sizeof(*p)` reports `4` then you know that the size of `int` (which is what `p` is pointing to in your case) is `4` bytes, which is normal on both 32 and 64 bit systems.

You would get the same result by doing `sizeof(int*)` and `sizeof(int)`.

Oh and a last note: To print the result of `sizeof` (which is of type `size_t`) then you should really use the `"z"` prefix, and an unsigned type specifier (since `size_t` is unsigned). For example `"%zu"`. Not doing that is technically *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so according to the above, integer size will be 4byte on 32 and 64 bit systems. And size of pointers itself is 8 byte.

Comment: @Jhon That is the *usual* size. But except `char` there are really no fixed-size primitive types (but there might be [fixed-width integer type-*aliases*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)). All the C specification says is the *minimum* sizes of the types.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(*p)` returns size of *type what the pointer points to* while `sizeof(p)` returns size of pointer itself.

In your case `*p = int` and `sizeof(int) = 4` on your machine, while you need `8` bytes to store memory address (address where `p` points to).

Comment: I recommend  rephrasing "pointer type" to "the type of what the pointer points to".

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(p)` is the size of the pointer itself. It depends on the size of the address bus. Which means for a 64-bit system, the address bus size will be 64-bit (8 bytes) so pointer will be 8 bytes long (that shows your system is 64-bit). And on a 32-bit system, it's size will be 32-bit(4 bytes).

`sizeof(*p)` is the size of pointer type i.e. `int` here. So usually `int` is of 32-bit long that is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax of a pointer variable:

```
var_type *variable;
```

e.g. `int *k;`

- '*' indicates that the variable 'k' is a pointer.

A pointer is also a variable whose value equals the address of the variable it points to.

Let's say we have a variable 'v' of type 'integer' that has a value of '100':

```
int v = 100;
```

When v is declared, it is stored in an address (a location on the memory). The space it occupies depends on the type of the variable. Let's assume a 64-bit system for the illustration below (variable type - size):

char - 1 byte;
int - 4 bytes;
float - 4 bytes

Thus, for an integer (int), the memory allocated is 4 bytes - at an address.

Recall that, int v = 100;

The address of v can be gotten with the ampersand operator prefix & (in C language): &v

```
printf("The address of v is: %lu", &v); //this prints the address of v in memory
```

Now, let's make use of our pointer - k:

```
k = &v; //pointer is assigned a value that is equal to the address of variable v
```

Take note that

> The default size of any "pointer" (assuming a 64-bit system) is 8
> bytes.

This means that our pointer k has a size of 8 bytes.

```
printf("The size of pointer k is: %d", sizeof(k));
```

> printf("Size of p = %d", sizeof(p));    // Here value is 8

Then the size of *k (which equals the value of the address of "integer" v) is 4 bytes.

Recall that the sizeof(int) = 4 bytes.

```
printf("The size of *k is: %d", sizeof(*k));
```

> printf("Size of *p = %d", sizeof(*p));   // Here value is 4

I really hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to Stack Overflow. I don't want to discourage further participation, on your part, but try to think if your answer offers anything new (that is, not in other answers) before posting. In this case, I'm not sure that it does.